# Stuck on what to do next in this program and the question is this. Create a Python program that finds a city and state from a given zip code?

Tags: python, list, file, exception

```
def main():

    print("\nZIPCODE LOOKUP PROGRAM")

    zlist,clist,slist=loadLists()

    userInput = searchLoop(zlist,clist,slist)

def loadLists():

# create a list

    try:

        zlist = []

        clist = []

        slist = []

# open the file

        zipFile = open("zipcodes.txt", "r")

        for nextline in zipFile:

            parsedlist = nextline.split(",")

            zlist.append(parsedlist[0])

            clist.append(parsedlist[1])

            slist.append(parsedlist[2])

        zipFile.close()

    except IOError:

        print("\nError - zipcodes.txt does not exist")

    return zlist,clist,slist

def searchLoop(zlist,clist,slist):

# search the zip code the user entered

    userInput = input("\nEnter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): ")

    while userInput != "":

        if userInput in zlist:

            where = zlist.index(userInput)

            print("\n" + "\tThe city is " + city + "and the state is" + state + ".")

            city = clist.index()

            state = slist.index()

        else:

            print("\n" + "\tZipcode does not exist")

        userInput = input("\nEnter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): ")

    return userInput

def findZipcode():

    # find the zip code, city, and state
    # what do I do about this

def printSearchResults():

#print the result

    print("\n" + "\tThe city is " + city + "and the state is" + state + ".")
```

This is what it is suppose to look like

Enter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): 90401
                  The city is SANTA MONICA and the state is CA.

Answer (score 0):

You have parallel arrays (i.e., related information shares the same index within the arrays) containing the zip code, state and city, and you are given a zip code to retrieve information for.

The idea then would be to find the index of the item in `zlist` that matches the given zip code, and use that index to extract the city and state from the other two arrays.

For example (Python-*looking* pseudo-code):

```
define getInfo(zlist, clist, slist, zipcode):
    for i = 0 to len(zlist) - 1 inclusive:
        if zlist[i] = zipcode:
            return clist[i] and slist[i]
    return nothing and nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

I cleaned up your code and I think the best approach is to use just a loop and a dictionary with keys to store the results, not lists.

```
def main():
    """Main function that triggers all other functions"""
    print("\nZIPCODE LOOKUP PROGRAM")
    my_list = load_lists()
    search_loop(my_list)

def load_lists():
    """Open file, create a list with the data parsed as a list of dicts"""
    my_list = []
    with open("zipcodes.txt", "r") as zip_file:
        for nextline in zip_file:
            parsedlist = nextline.split(",")
            my_list.append({"Zip":parsedlist[0], "City":parsedlist[1], "State":parsedlist[2]})
    return my_list

def search_loop(my_list):
    """Search the zip code the user entered using a loop.
    Then print that dictionary formatted for readability"""
    user_input = input("\nEnter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): ")
    while user_input != "":
        for item in my_list:
            if str(user_input) == item['Zip']:
                print(f"\n\tThe city is {item['City']} and the state is {item['State']}.")
                break # No need to check other results since we found it
        else:
            print("\n\tZipcode does not exist")
        userInput = input("\nEnter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): ")
    return

main() # Run the program
```

**Result:**

```
ZIPCODE LOOKUP PROGRAM  
Enter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): 1234  
   The city is TestCity and the state is Testing.  

Enter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): 4567  
   The city is MadeUpCity and the state is MadeUp.
```

**Things to have in mind:**

- Use `with` to read files such as .txt, it will open and close them automatically and you'll avoid most of the errors that way. [Read about it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/).
- You can use [docstrings](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/docstrings-python) (triple quoted string) as first things on what a function should do, to avoid the need of multiple comments everywhere.
- And please don't use **CamelCase** in python except for classes. This
  is explained in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- f-strings makes prints prettier. `f:"this is {city} and this is {state}."` instead of `"this is " + city + " and this is " + state + "."`